# domain extension removal behavior

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache

I have a strange thing happening with php files.  As an example:

```
domain.com/test.php
domain.com/test
domain.com/test/some/other/directory/that/does/not/exist
```

All three of the above link structures will resolve at the test.php file.  What causes this?  Is there a setting in the php.ini file or the httpd.conf file or an .htaccess file that has a setting which controls this behavior?  This does not happen with html files just php files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution or reason that I found that causes this is a setting in the httpd.conf file that turns on multiviews.  This can be disabled in an .htaccess file using the following.

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have mod_rewrite turned on with a rule to do that.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: That was my guess as well, but I don't know where that rule would be or how it would be written.

Comment: It would be in your httpd.conf file or in your .htaccess file.  Generally you need to have "RewriteEngine On" somewhere in your httpd.conf file or your .htaccess file to turn the module on.  So check for that first.